# "Binomiable" numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Is there a nice criterion to determine whether a given natural $m$ can be written as a binomial number $\binom{n}{k}$ with $1 < k < n-1$?

I've been thinking on this problem with a friend and all we concluded is that primes aren't "binomiables".

> **CLAIM 1.** Primes aren't "binomiables".
>
> *Proof.* Let $p$ a prime and suppose $p = \binom{n}{k}$.
>
> - If $n$ is prime, then $n$ must be equals $p$, because $n\mid \binom{n}{k}$. But, in this case, $n\mid\mid \binom{n}{k}$, so $k=1$. (This would work to prime powers too.)
> - If $n$ is composed, note that $\binom{n}{k} = p$ implies, *a fortiori*, that $p\mid \binom{n}{k}$ and consequently $p\leqslant n$. But under our conditions, $\binom{n}{k} > n$, contradiction. $\square$

Also, I've already saw in [Proofs from THE BOOK](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783662442043) the problem "Binomial coefficients are (almost) never powers", and although it is highly related, it doesn't provide much insight towards this problem (at least as far as I understood).

---

**EDIT:** Prime powers aren't binomiables too!

Let's state three results first:

1. **Lemma.** *Let $p$ a prime. If $p\mid n$ and $0<k<p$, then $p\mid \binom{n}{k}$.*

   *Proof.* Let $n= pm$ and assume $0<k<p$. Consider the Vandermonde's identity:

   $$\binom{pm}{k} = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{p}{j}\binom{p(m-1)}{k-j}.$$

   It follows that $\binom{pm}{k}\equiv \binom{p(m-1)}{k} \mod{p}$ (the
   term $j=0$ in the sum). Repeating it $m$ times, we conclude
   $\binom{pm}{k}\equiv \binom{p}{k} \mod{p}$, and from $p\mid
       \binom{p}{k}$ follows our statement. $\square$
2. **Bertrand's postulate.** *If $n\geqslant 2k$, then the binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ has a prime factor $q > k$.*
3. **Theorem.** [Erdös] *The binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ is never a perfect power for $4\leqslant k\leqslant n-4$.*

   (This is the paragraph I mentioned in [Proofs from THE BOOK](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783662442043).)

So there is only two cases to analyse, $k=2$ and $k=3$. In both cases we can assume $n \geqslant 6$.

> **CLAIM 2.** Prime powers aren't "binomiables".
>
> *Proof.* Let $p$ a prime, $m>1$, and suppose $p^m = \binom{n}{k}$.
>
> - If $k=2$, then $p^m = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. By Bertrand's postulate, $p\neq 2$. Now observe that $\gcd(n, n-1) = 1$, so
>     $$ p^m \mid n\quad \text{xor}\quad p^m\mid n-1. $$
>     Then:
>     $$2 =\frac{n(n-1)}{p^m} \geqslant n-1 \implies n \leqslant 3,$$
>     that contradicts $n\geqslant 6$.
> - If $k=3$, then $p^m = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$. Bertrand's postulate allows us to take $p\neq 2,3$. Hence, similarly to the previous case, we can deduce:
>     $$p^m \mid n \quad \text{xor}\quad p^m\mid n-1 \quad \text{xor} \quad p^m\mid n-2.$$
>     But then:
>     $$ 6 = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{p^m} \geqslant (n-1)(n-2) \implies n \leqslant 4,$$
>     a contradiction. $\square$

---

**EDIT 2:** I've just realized that I didn't use the Lemma at all. Anyway, I think I'll let it here, it may be useful someday hahaha

Comment: Perhaps you could draw up a Pascal's triangle, see what numbers do and don't appear, and see if you find a pattern?

Comment: A list of these numbers is at https://oeis.org/A006987 - there doesn't seem to be much there.  In particular, if there were a nice criterion I'd expect it to be listed there.  But it's a fun problem - keep playing around with it!

Comment: Perhaps a clearer condition would be $\binom nk>n$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer for a special case: if $\sqrt{8n+1}$ is an odd integer, then $n$ is a binomial coefficient of the form $n \choose 2$.  Such a formula is possible because $n \choose 2$ is quadratic in $n$ and therefore has a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think theres a single simple criterion, but one could construct an algorithm for determining it with time complexity of $O((\ln c)^2)$ binomial coefficients or $O((\ln c)^3)$ multiplicaitons. Besides it may be unknown or hard to determine totally certainly whether the number is actually prime or not.

What we can use is to estimate the coefficients:

$$\binom{n}{k} 
= {\prod_0^k (n-j)\over\prod_0^k j} 
= {\prod_0^k (n-(k/2)+k/2-j)\over\prod_0^k j} \\
= \begin{cases}
{(n-k/2)\prod_0^{(k-1)/2} (n-(k/2)-k/2+j)(n-(k/2)+k/2-j)\over\prod_0^k j} =
{(n-k/2)\prod_0^{(k-1)/2} (n-(k/2))^2-(k/2+j)^2\over\prod_0^k j} 
& \text{ if } k \text{ is odd } \\
{\prod_0^{k/2} (n-(k/2))^2-(k/2+j)^2\over\prod_0^k j} 
& \text{ if } k \text{ is even } \\
\end{cases} \\
\le {(n-k/2)^k\over k!}$$

We also can estimate it from below:

$${(n-k)^k\over k!} \le \binom{n}{k} \le {(n-k/2)^k\over k!}$$

So given $k$ we have an estimate for $n$

$$(k!c)^{1/k} \le n \le (k!c)^{1/k} + k/2$$

Also since we only have to consider $2k<n$ we can use the estimate:

$$\binom{n}{k} \ge \binom{2k}{k} = {(2k)!\over k!k!}$$

So we don't have to consider $k$ with $(2k)!/(k!)^2 > c$ and since it's increasing we can terminate the algorithm once it happens.

---

Take for example the numbers $8008$ and $8009$ (the later being prime)

We have the ranges of $n$ depending on $k$ as:

$$\begin{matrix}
k & n_{min} & n_{max} & \binom{2k}{k} \\
\hline
2 & 127 & 127 & 6\\
3 & 37 & 37 & 20 \\
4 & 21 & 22 & 70 \\
5 & 16 & 18 & 252 \\
6 & 14 & 16 & 924 \\
7 & 13 & 15 & 3432 \\
8 & & & 12870
\end{matrix}$$

That is we only have to consider
$\binom{127}{2}$,
$\binom{37}{3}$,
$\binom{21}{4}$,
$\binom{22}{4}$,
$\binom{16}{5}$,
$\binom{17}{5}$,
$\binom{18}{5}$,
$\binom{14}{6}$,
$\binom{15}{6}$,
$\binom{16}{6}$,
$\binom{13}{7}$,
$\binom{14}{7}$ and
$\binom{15}{7}$. Calculating these reveals that $8008 = \binom{16}{6}$ and $8009$ is none of them.

The time complexity is due to stirlings formula for the termination condition:

$$\ln{(2k)!\over (k!)^2} = (2k \ln (2k) - 2k + O(\ln 2k))-2(k\ln k - k+O(\ln k)) \\
= 2k(\ln 2+\ln k) - 2k - 2k\ln k + 2k + O(\ln k) 
= 2k\ln 2 + O(ln k) < \ln(c)$$

So we have to consider $O(\ln(c))$  values of $k$ and for each of those $k/2$ values of $n$ making it $O((\ln(c))^2)$ binomial coefficients.

Comment: That's a really nice answer! I particularly liked how this algorithm sheds light over the structure of possible binomial representations. Thank you for your careful considerations :)

Answer (score 1):

*Just some comment so far:*

---

First case: we search cases where ${ a_j \choose 2 }=b_j^m$

By brute force I found the following very likely pattern, by which the sequences $a_j$ and $b_j^2$ can directly be generated. In all cases $m=2$, I had no case with $m \gt 2$ so far, except of course where $b_1 = 1$ - here the exponent $m$ can take any value.

- The sequence of $a_j$  is
  $$ a_j = \{2,9,50,289,...\}_{j=1,2,3,...}
  $$
  and has the iteration formula $$a_{j}\underset{j\ge3}=6a_{j-1}-a_{j-2}-2$$ 
  The question of whether $a_j$ can be prime has at least for each second $a_j$ a simple answer by this formula: if $a_{j-2}$ is even, then also $a_j$. And since $a_1=2$ is even, all $a_j$ with odd $j$ are composite. It seems also that all $a_j$ at even index $j$ are squares, however I didn't try to derive an analogue conclusion for this from the recursion-formula so far. At least, under the assumption, that the partial sequence $c_{j}=a_{2j}=\{9,289,577,...\}$ has indeed only squares $c_j^2$ then we have a recursion $ c_j =  6c_{j-1} - c_{j-2}    $ and this would also exclude $a_{2j}$ being prime.
- The sequence $b_j$ is
  $$\begin{array}{} b_j^2 = \{1,36,1225,41616,...\}  \\
     b_j   = \{1, 6,  35,   204,...\} & \text{with iteration formula} \qquad b_{j}\underset{j\ge3}=6b_{j-1}-b_{j-2} \\
  \end{array}$$

---

second case: we search cases where ${ a_j \choose 3 }=b_j^m$    where $m\ge2$

First examples by brute force ($a_j \le 20,000,000$):
$$ \begin{array} {r|r|rrrll} 
 j & a_j & {a_j \choose 3}=b_j^m &  & b_j &\text{^}m \\ \hline
 1 &  3    &    1  &=&  1 &\text{^}0 \ldots \infty  \\
 2 & 4   &     4  &=&  2 &\text{^}2   \\ 
 3 &50  &  19600  &=& 140&\text{^}2  \\
 \end{array} $$

*Interestingly, W|A didn't find the solutions except the trivial one where $b_j=0$*

Answer (score -1):

I know they are composite.

To show this, suppose not, that is, $\binom mn=p$, a prime. Then $m\ge p$. Since we are excluding the trivial cases, $m\ge p+1$ and then

$$\binom mn\ge\binom{p+1}2=p\cdot\frac{p+1}2\ge\frac32p>p$$

a contradiction.

But not every composite number is a non-trivial binomial coefficient. For example, $9$ is not.

Comment: I already remarked that primes aren't binomiables in the body of the question (in the big yellow box!).