# Is it known whether a triangular number can be any power with exponent greater than $2$?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Here :

[Who can prove that a triangular number cannot be a cube, fourth power or fifth power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185585/who-can-prove-that-a-triangular-number-cannot-be-a-cube-fourth-power-or-fifth-p)

I asked how it can be proven that a triangular number (a number of the form $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$) cannot be a cube, fourth power or fifth power and lulu posted very useful results which probably solve the problem completely.

But even more seems to be true :

CONJECTURE : A triangle number cannot be a power $k^s$ with $k\ge 2$ , $s\ge 3$

The conjecture is true for $n\le 10^9$ and I currently verify the range $[10^9,10^{10}]$ without having found a counter-example yet.

> Is it known whether this conjecture is true ?

Comment: Erdös showed that binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ are never powers for $4\le k\le n-4$, and discussed the cases $k=2$ and $k=3$. For $k=2$ we have the triangular numbers $\binom{n+1}{2}$, where we also can say something, see claim 2 [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359580/binomiable-numbers), and Erdös paper.

Comment: Your conjecture is true for $n=4k$ where $k$ is an odd number.